# How to find column and table name when SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException thrown

Tags: java, jdbc, exception

How can I find which column in which table cause the `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` ?
when I catch this exception, only message (as plain text) and `SQLState` exists. but I cant find table name and column separated for generating user friendly message

Answer (score 2):

Like all SQLExceptions, the details depend on your DB vendor. If you're lucky, you can parse `exception.getMessage()` for this information. But there is no general Java-side method for this.

Answer (score 0):

The stack does contain the name of the unique key that was violated. You can compare the names of the key that you've created parallel to the database that you're querying on in the catch clause and can generate error message accordingly.